# Is it possible to use HTTP_INTERCEPTORS within a nested lazy module?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I have a `FooModule` which is nested inside the `AppModule`:

`AppModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.model';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

`FooModule`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthInterceptorService } from '../auth/auth-interceptor.service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FooModule {}
```

The `FooModule` is being loaded via lazy loading:

`AppRoutingModule`:

```
const appRoutes : Routes = [
    {
        path: "foos",
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("./foos/foos.module").then(m => m.FoosModule)
    }
]

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

But only when I moves the `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` into the `AppModule` the http-s are intercepted, **Is there way to make the interceptors to work from the `FooModule`**.

I'm asking cause the interceptor doing a specific job of adding Authorization which is relevant only to the `FooModule`.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20575

Comment: Just to summarize @MikeOne's link: There is a bug in Angular that causes interceptors to be lost when `HttpClientModule` is imported multiple times. It's only supposed to be imported once at the root module. So if you import a 3rd-party module that imports `HttpClientModule`, then you lose your interceptors and you have to log a bug with the maintainers of the 3rd-party package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it is possible to load `HTTP_INTERCEPTORS` via a nested lazy loaded module, I was only missing the import of `HttpClientModule` inside the nested module:

```
@NgModule({
  import: HttpClientModule,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptorService,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class FooModule {}
```

But, because `HttpClientModule` is a singleton it should be defined only once, and the best place for it is inside `AppModule`. So I've ended up with moving the interceptors and the http client to be imported from `AppModule` while modifying the `resolve` to be conditional resolver based on the `req.url`:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url == this._config.SecretAPI) {
        //Add Authorization Header:
        const modifiedReq = req.clone({ 
            headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', this._authService.authorizationHeaderValue)
        });
        return next.handle(modifiedReq);
    }
    else {
        return next.handle(modifiedReq);
    }
}
```